# tape.gradient takes a lot of time (or stucked) with RNN GRU model

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have a trained  keras model, I'm trying to find the gradient of `target_preds` with respect of `sample_inputs` in the trained model. I tried to do it with CNN model and it computed in couple of seconds. When I insert a model that is RNN, the function it take it seems that the same code executes for long time (I didn't even let it finished, but when I interrupt the code -it (stuck)/(is running) at line   `grads = tape.gradient(target_preds, sample_inputs)` ).

I'm using Tensorflow 2.3.0

The relevant code is below:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch(sample_inputs)
    preds = model(sample_inputs)
    if (target_range is None):
        target_preds = preds[:, :]
    else:
        target_preds = preds[:, target_range]

if(jacobian):
    grads = tape.jacobian(target_preds, sample_inputs)
else:
    grads = tape.gradient(target_preds, sample_inputs)
return grads
```